# GridView or Grid Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, gridview

I'm trying to create a simple grid in a Windows 8 Universal app. 
Below is my goal.

Row1Col1   Row1Col2    Row1Col3

Row2Col1    Row2Col2  Row2Col3

Row3Col1    Row3Col2  Row3Col3

```
<Grid x:Name="Grid1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="217" Margin="557,135,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="433">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Grid.Background>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    </Grid>
```

I'd like to set up even spaced rows and columns in XAML and add the Text labels in code.

Something like:

Grid.Row1.Col1.Text="Row1Col1";
Grid.Row1.Col2.Text="Row1Col2";

A short XAML snippet and piece of c# code would be helpful.

Here is my xaml so far.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add text to the different cells in the grid i've added TextBlocks and placed them appropriately:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="40"/>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Name="r1c1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock Name="r1c2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock Name="r1c3" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock Name="r2c1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock Name="r2c2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock Name="r2c3" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock Name="r3c1" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock Name="r3c2" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock Name="r3c3" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

As an example, I've altered my code behind to the following:

```
private int N = 3;
private TextBlock[,] gridText;
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    InitializeGridText();

    MethodThatChangesText();
}

private void InitializeGridText()
{
    gridText = new TextBlock[N, N];
    gridText[0, 0] = r1c1;
    gridText[0, 1] = r1c2;
    gridText[0, 2] = r1c3;
    gridText[1, 0] = r2c1;
    gridText[1, 1] = r2c2;
    gridText[1, 2] = r2c3;
    gridText[2, 0] = r3c1;
    gridText[2, 1] = r3c2;
    gridText[2, 2] = r3c3;
}

void MethodThatChangesText()
{
    // Some Logic Here

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            gridText[i, j].Text = String.Format("Row{0}Col{1}", i + 1, j + 1);
}
```

Depending on what you're trying to do, you can add your own logic and have this method get called in response to some event (e.g. button click...).

Comment: Thanks Frank.  I was hoping a bit more direct way to assign text to the grid, but for now your solution works.